# Make <img> act like a text in search engines

Tags: html, image, seo

I have image with phone number on it:

[image: showing a telephone number]

I want to let other people find the page where this image is, by searching "1-700-700-690" on Google. Just as if the HTML tag would be:

```
<div> 1-700-700-690 </div>
```

I tried:

```
<img alt="1-700-700-690" src="http://hashef.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Moked-Telephoni2.png" width="295" height="62" />
```

But it doesn't work (tried find the page on Google).

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Why not just put your number directly in the webpage?

Comment: Cause there are a lot of pages with that image and I need to change it in a lot of places

Comment: Can't you just do a global find-and-replace? With Notepad++ I could make that change in thousands of files within seconds, and most of that time is spent waiting for the computer to do it. Alternatively, if you have any server-side scripting such as PHP... <?php require("phone_number.txt"); ?> and that file can contain your phone number.

Comment: How long did you wait between changing it and checking in Google Search?

Answer (score 1):

One of these two workarounds might work for you:

1) Place `<p>1-700-700-690</p>` directly before or after your image and set font-size to 1px and change the font color to the background color.

2) Use `<meta>` tags in your head that include the phone number. This should help with the indexing of your page. Documentation can be found directly on Google, e.g. [see this link here.](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en)